# How do I put my Screen size in an alert? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, size, screen, alert, resolution

I want my alert to pop up and show me what size my screen resolution is.

```
alert("Your Screen Resolution is ...")
```

Comment: Have you attempted any research yet?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript+screen+resolution

Comment: @ceejayoz Better: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+screen+resolution `:)`

Comment: @ceejayoz I think lmgtfy is more appropriate, but I guess StackOverflow is on to me

Answer (score 6):

```
alert( 'Your screen resolution is ' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height );
```

Comment: lol, you a$$, beat me to it, i'll delete mine

Comment: @SpYk3HH I actually took my time, it's late... `:P`